# C# Application, Tick events and waiting

Tags: c#, timer

I'm writing an application that will automate one of our manual webform input processes

Everything is working good except for one problem.

I have a Timer setup, that becomes enabled on a certain page. The Timer tick event is checking the page every 100 milliseconds for ajax changes applied to the page. Once the ajax updates are detected, the Timer is disabled, the result is stored, and the program SHOULD continue executing code beyond that point.

The problem is the code continues to execute while the Timer is enabled.

In the logic, as soon as the appropriate page loads, I have

t2.Enabled = true;

Which immediately works as it should, looking at the page until the update is discovered

But the code immediately following the Enabled property is executing without pause, causing many issues, such as variables changing before the result is discovered.

How can I have the code following this line wait until the t2.Enabled is set back to false (which is done within the t2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) method

```
void t2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string postVerifyHTML = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            postVerifyHTML = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
        }
        // if page fails, restart
        catch
        {
            wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.website.com"), "_self");
        }

        if (postVerifyHTML.IndexOf("indentifier html") != -1)
        {
            NameSearchResults[nameCounter].Visited = true;
            nameCounter++;
            ResultFound = true;
            t2.Enabled = false;
        }

        t2TimerCount++;

        if (t2TimerCount >= 100)
        {
            // TRY AGAIN
            wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.website.com"), "_self");
        }

    }



    protected void wb_SearchForm_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pageHTML = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

        // Look at the page with the name result
        if (pageHTML.IndexOf("Search Results: Verify") != -1)
        {
            //If the page has this input, a verification is available
            if (pageHTML.IndexOf("txtSSN") != -1)
            {
                HtmlElement txtSSN = wb.Document.GetElementById("txtSSN");
                txtSSN.SetAttribute("value", curSearchRecord.UniqueId.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", ""));
                HtmlElement submitBtn = wb.Document.GetElementById("ibtnVerify");
                submitBtn.InvokeMember("click");

                t2.Enabled = true;
                // I need the code after this point to wait until the Timer is disabled

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Timer is running on a different thread to your UI code, which is why your execution is continuing. Why don't you simply check the Enabled state of the Timer to determine whether or not to continue the execution? Alternatively use the callback of your ajax code to fire off the continuation code.

Comment: I tried putting 
                    while (t2.Enabled)
                    {
                    }     After the line, but that just gets the application stuck inside that loop

Comment: You should probabaly post the code so that it's clear where the rest of the code resides, but a while loop is not really appropriate anyway - you need to use an IF that should then be tested whenever the Timer tick event is fired.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your code is doing but if the code block in your tick event that disable the timer is an indication that the remaining code can be executed then you could execute it from there (i.e. move the "// I need the code after this " into a method and call it from within the Tick event.

Comment: However, I would suggest hookin up to your AJAX callback to initiate the continuation and checking whether you need the Timer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this is the best method to to it but you can do a do an if like so :

```
if (t2.Enabled=False)
   {
       //the code you want to run when the timer is off
   }
```

but you have to make sure that it is in another timer (t3 in this case if you want) otherwise it wont check every tick if t2 is off to run the code while it is.
sorry if the answer is not more detailed, I lacked details in your question as well.

Good programing :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I think I figured out a different solution, where I move the post-Timer code to a separate method, and call the method at the appropriate time within t2_Tick. So far this seems like a solid fix :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) as a member of your class

After you enable the Timer, you call the WaitOne method

After your disable the Timer, you call the Set method

```
private ManualResetevent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

void t2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string postVerifyHTML = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        postVerifyHTML = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
    }
    // if page fails, restart
    catch
    {
        wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.website.com"), "_self");
    }

    if (postVerifyHTML.IndexOf("indentifier html") != -1)
    {
        NameSearchResults[nameCounter].Visited = true;
        nameCounter++;
        ResultFound = true;
        t2.Enabled = false;

        //Set the mre to unblock the blocked code
        mre.Set();
    }

    t2TimerCount++;

    if (t2TimerCount >= 100)
    {
        // TRY AGAIN
        wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.website.com"), "_self");
    }

}

protected void wb_SearchForm_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pageHTML = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

    // Look at the page with the name result
    if (pageHTML.IndexOf("Search Results: Verify") != -1)
    {
        //If the page has this input, a verification is available
        if (pageHTML.IndexOf("txtSSN") != -1)
        {
            HtmlElement txtSSN = wb.Document.GetElementById("txtSSN");
            txtSSN.SetAttribute("value", curSearchRecord.UniqueId.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", ""));
            HtmlElement submitBtn = wb.Document.GetElementById("ibtnVerify");
            submitBtn.InvokeMember("click");

            t2.Enabled = true;

            //The code will block until Set() is called on mre
            mre.WaitOne();

            //The rest of your code here

}
```